# GCC (AVR) Assembly: Subtract label address

Tags: gcc, assembly, avr, avr-gcc

I am trying to accomplish:

```
LABEL:
....
subi r18, LABEL
```

I need to subtract address of a label from a register. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
subi r16, pm_lo8(LABEL)
sbci r17, pm_hi8(LABEL)
```

as answered on avrfreaks:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=857982#857982

reference document:
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/AVR_002dModifiers.html#AVR_002dModifiers

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not that familiar with AVR assembler, this is just what I could gauge from reading a few webpages. I'm also assuming that your addresses are 16-bit.

```
; Address you wish to subtract the label from in R16 (low):R17 (high)

SUBI R16, LOW(LABEL)
SBCI R17, HIGH(LABEL) ; Omit this part if you have < 256 Bytes of ram
```